# a possible issue with the Chrome WebDriver or the Chrome browser itself in python

Tags: unity-game-engine, openai-api

Hello im working on a project too let chat gpt see in the in game world in unity by sending a screenshot to chat gpt via a custom text only format which only chat gpt can understand when given a special prompt here is the python code this python code uses https://github.com/terry3041/pyChatGPT by the way I could not use chat Gpt API because its too expensive and the unity text on the canvas wa supposed to display chat GPTs response/ reaction to the image but Im unaware if that works

```
import sys
import socket
import threading
import requests
import logging
from PIL import Image
import io
from pyChatGPT import ChatGPT

# Configure logging to log errors
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', level=logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Create a file handler for error logging
error_handler = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
error_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
error_handler.setFormatter(error_formatter)
logger.addHandler(error_handler)

# Function to decode the custom format string into an image
def decode_custom_format_string(custom_format_string):
    print("Received custom format string:", custom_format_string)

    encoded_pixels = custom_format_string.strip().split()

    # Extract position and color information from each encoded pixel
    decoded_pixels = []
    for encoded_pixel in encoded_pixels:
        position_color = encoded_pixel.strip("()").split(")")[0]
        position, color = position_color.split(",")
        print("Position:", position)
        print("Color:", color)

        r, g, b = map(int, color.split(","))
        decoded_pixels.append(((int(position.split(",")[0]), int(position.split(",")[1])), (r, g, b)))

    # Create a new image and set the pixel colors based on the decoded data
    image = Image.new("RGB", (512, 512))
    for pixel in decoded_pixels:
        position, color = pixel
        image.putpixel(position, color)

    return image


# Function to handle client requests
def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
    object1_custom_format = None
    object2_custom_format = None

    # Initialize ChatGPT with the session token
    session_token = 'TokenHere'  # Replace with your session token
    api = ChatGPT(session_token)

    while True:
        # Receive data from the client
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            break

        # Process the received data
        if data.startswith("object1_custom_format:"):
            object1_custom_format = data.replace("object1_custom_format:", "")
        elif data.startswith("object2_custom_format:"):
            object2_custom_format = data.replace("object2_custom_format:", "")

        if object1_custom_format is not None and object2_custom_format is not None:
            # Both object1 and object2 images have been received

            # Process the object1 image
            object1_image = decode_custom_format_string(object1_custom_format)

            # Process the object2 image
            object2_image = decode_custom_format_string(object2_custom_format)

            # Send the initial prompt to ChatGPT for object2
            prompt = """Hello ChatGPT! I would like you to analyze the second object's image in a custom format.

The custom format represents the image by encoding each pixel's color and position. The format is designed as follows: Each pixel is represented by its color and position in a comma-separated format. The color is represented in RGB format, where each component (red, green, and blue) ranges from 0 to 255, indicating the intensity of that color. The position is represented by the x and y coordinates of the pixel on a grid, also ranging from 0 to 255.

For example, a pixel with color (R: 255, G: 0, B: 128) and position (x: 100, y: 200) would be represented as: Color - R:255, G:0, B:128; Position - x:100, y:200.

Your task is to analyze the image encoded in this format and provide an explanation of what you see. Additionally, please suggest a method to compress the image to reduce its size while preserving important details.

Thank you!"""

            # Send a message to ChatGPT
            response = api.send_message(prompt)

            # Extract the generated text from the response
            result = response['message']

            # Print the response from ChatGPT
            print("ChatGPT response:", result)

            # Send response back to the client
            client_socket.send(result.encode())

            # Send the encoded pixel information as separate messages to ChatGPT for object2
            pixel_prompt = "Pixel: Position - {position}, Color - {color}"
            for pixel in object2_custom_format.split():
                position, color = pixel.strip("()").split(")")[0].split(",")
                r, g, b = map(int, color.split(","))
                pixel_data = pixel_prompt.format(position=position, color=f"R:{r}, G:{g}, B:{b}")

                # Send a message to ChatGPT
                response = api.send_message(pixel_data)

                result = response['message']
                client_socket.send(result.encode())

        else:
            # Handle other types of data or commands
            # Here you can add logic to handle additional types of data or commands
            # For example, if there are other specific commands or data formats you need to handle
            # you can add the corresponding code here

            # Example: Handle a specific command called "other_command"
            if data == "other_command":
                # Handle the "other_command" here
                pass

    # Close the client socket
    client_socket.close()


# Function to start the server and listen for connections
def start_server(host, port):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    try:
        server_socket.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        logger.error("Error in socket binding: %s", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    server_socket.listen(1)
    print("Please note this takes a awhile to output somthing somtimes so waiting for Unity connection on {}:{}".format(host, port))

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Connected to Unity at {}:{}".format(client_address[0], client_address[1]))

        # Create a new thread to handle the client connection
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client_connection, args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "localhost"
    port = 9999

    # Start the server
    start_server(host, port)
```

here is my unity code which connects too the python server

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class ChatGPTWithEyes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera object1Camera;
    public Camera object2Camera;
    public Text chatText;

    private bool isWaitingForResponse = false;
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Connect to the Python server
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    private void ConnectToServer()
    {
        // Create a TCP client and connect to the server
        client = new TcpClient("localhost", 9999);
        stream = client.GetStream();

        // Start receiving messages from the server in a separate thread
        StartReceivingMessages();
    }

    private void StartReceivingMessages()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        // Begin receiving messages from the server
        stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReceiveMessageCallback, buffer);
    }

    private void ReceiveMessageCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        byte[] buffer = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // Convert the received data to a string
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Display the received message in the chat text UI
            chatText.text = message;

            // Continue receiving messages from the server
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReceiveMessageCallback, buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            // The server has disconnected, clean up resources
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Only capture and send screenshots if not waiting for a response from the server
        if (!isWaitingForResponse)
        {
            // Capture screenshots of game view from the two objects
            Texture2D object1Screenshot = CaptureScreenshot(object1Camera);
            Texture2D object2Screenshot = CaptureScreenshot(object2Camera);

            // Convert screenshots to custom format strings
            string object1CustomFormat = ConvertToCustomFormat(object1Screenshot);
            string object2CustomFormat = ConvertToCustomFormat(object2Screenshot);

            // Send screenshots to the Python server for processing
            SendMessageToServer(object1CustomFormat, object2CustomFormat);
        }
    }

    private Texture2D CaptureScreenshot(Camera camera)
    {
        RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 24);
        camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        camera.Render();

        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        Texture2D screenshot = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        screenshot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        screenshot.Apply();

        camera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

        return screenshot;
    }

    private string ConvertToCustomFormat(Texture2D texture)
{
    StringBuilder customFormat = new StringBuilder();

    for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            // Get the color of the pixel at (x, y)
            Color pixelColor = texture.GetPixel(x, y);

            // Encode the pixel color and position in the custom format
            string encodedColor = EncodeColor(pixelColor);
            string encodedPosition = EncodePosition(x, y);

            // Append the encoded color and position to the custom format string
            customFormat.Append("(");
            customFormat.Append(encodedPosition);
            customFormat.Append(")");
            customFormat.Append(encodedColor);
            customFormat.Append(" ");
        }
    }

    // Return the final custom format string
    return customFormat.ToString();
}

private string EncodeColor(Color color)
{
    // Convert the color to RGB values (0-255)
    int r = (int)(color.r * 255);
    int g = (int)(color.g * 255);
    int b = (int)(color.b * 255);

    // Encode the RGB values as a string
    string encodedColor = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", r, g, b);

    return encodedColor;
}

private string EncodePosition(int x, int y)
{
    // Encode the position as a string
    string encodedPosition = string.Format("{0},{1}", x, y);

    return encodedPosition;
}


    private void SendMessageToServer(string object1CustomFormat, string object2CustomFormat)
    {
        string message = $"object1_custom_format:{object1CustomFormat}\nobject2_custom_format:{object2CustomFormat}";

        // Convert the message to bytes and send it to the server
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        // Mark as waiting for a response from the server
        isWaitingForResponse = true;
    }
}
```

and im getting this error in python im getting

```
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:2665
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0116A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x010FC4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x01005220]
        (No symbol) [0x00FFB355]
        (No symbol) [0x01025C68]
        (No symbol) [0x010206B4]
        (No symbol) [0x01020491]
        (No symbol) [0x01050C55]
        (No symbol) [0x0105093C]
        (No symbol) [0x0104A536]
        (No symbol) [0x010282DC]
        (No symbol) [0x010293DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013CAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0140A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0140456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011F51E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x01105F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x01102328]
        (No symbol) [0x0110240B]
        (No symbol) [0x010F4FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76F47D69+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x773FBB9B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x773FBB1F+191]
```

I expected too work my first idea was too use a unity script that detects the python process and gets the data from it locally running instead of server and client but that did not work

made sure Id have the correct version of Chrome WebDriver installed that matches my Chrome browser version

well id could not do that because chrome just closes automatically so is there an alternative I can use which would maybe made sense I got this error because chrome could not be reached because its task just gets killed every dang time I open it